# A question about triangle inequality applied to a norm

Tags: probability-theory

$X_t$ is a Markov chain and $Z_t$ is a random variable whose distribution doesn't matter for my question. I have $Z_{2t} - Z_t = \xi G_{2t}$ where $\xi\sim $Bernoulli$(1/2)$ random variable and is independent of $G_{2t}$ random variable. Then the statement is that by triangle inequality it follows that

$$||P_x\{X_{Z_{2t}-Z_t} = \cdot\} - P_y\{X_{Z_{2t}-Z_t} = \cdot\}||\leq \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}||P_x\{X_{G_{2t}} = \cdot\} - P_y\{X_{G_{2t}} = \cdot\}||$$

May I know how it follows from triangle inequality?

Comment: If $\xi = 0,$ then you are calculating the distance between the measures $\varepsilon_x$ and $\varepsilon_y,$ which is $1.$